# jQuery Weekcalendar setDaysToShow function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins

Can you tell me  how to call the `setDaysToShow` function of the jQuery weekcalendar plugin? I do not know how to pass the `days`.

This is from the [docs](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/Public-methods):

```
$(“#calendar”).weekCalendar(“setDaysToShow”); // Changes how many days are shown (see the daysToShow option)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#calendar').weekCalendar('setDaysToShow', value);
```

or you can do it when you initialize by passing it as an option

```
$('#calendar').weekCalendar({'setDaysToShow': value});
```